# Find minimal number of elements in matrix.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, cellular-automata

Consider a $A \in Mat_{n}(\{+1,-1\})$ (square matrix consisted of +1,-1).

Now we can make and operation *majority* , i.e. $a_{i,j} = $ median of his neighborhoods(closest elements around him, i.e. closest 3,5, or 8 elements).

*If number of elements are equal , then majority return -1 , i.e.:*
$\begin{pmatrix}
  -1& -1 &1\\
  -1& 1 &1\\
  -1& 1& 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
  -1& 1 &1\\
  -1& -1 &1\\
  1& 1& 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ medium element go to $-1$, because of there are equal number of *+1/-1*.

After this we will have another matrix. Obviously there could be three situations (depends of initial positions of +1/-1): after some number of majority operations there will be **1** matrix,**-1** matrix or matrix will cycled.

So my question: does there some estimates on number of $1$($-1$) to get **1** matrix (**-1** matrix).

I've thought that it should be $O(n^{2})$ (actually I thought that $n(n-1)$ is enough for $n>3$).

For easier understanding I've left an example:

$\begin{pmatrix}
  -1& -1\\
  1& -1
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
  -1& -1\\
  -1& -1
\end{pmatrix} $

*Added* example for $n=3$

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1& 1\\
  -1& -1& 1\\
  1 & 1 &-1
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
  -1& 1& 1\\
  1& 1& 1\\
  -1 & -1 &1
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
  1& 1& 1\\
  1& 1& 1\\
  1 & 1 &1
\end{pmatrix}$

*EDIT 1 :*

I've tried to consider such sequence in OEIS. 
First of all I've found that for $n =2$ we have $f(2) = 3$, $n = 3$ we have $f(3) = $7 , if $n = 4$ we have $f(4) = 11$ and probably for $n = 5$ $f(5) = 17$.

I've considered some sequences but for some large $n$ this sequences became near the $n/2$. Which contradict with my logic.

Comment: What is the meaning of your 3rd paragraph? How do you transform the matrices?It is confusing me..

Comment: @AvinashN:  each cell simultaneously looks at its (up to) four neighbors and is set equal to the majority, so one that has three $1$ neighbors and one $-1$ is set to $1$.  Ties are resolved by going to $-1$.  It is similar to Conway's game of Life, with a four cell neighborhood and perturbations for the edges/corners.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you sir. One more doubt. The (2,3) position of second 3×3 marix is right?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Nor is the (3,1) in the third $3 \times 3$. Fixing the $(2,3)$ in the second will flip $(1,3), (2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ in the third.  OP, please check these.  I suspect this goes to $-1$

Comment: @AvinashN added example.

Comment: @openspace I got it. Thanks much.

Comment: @RossMillikan am I right that $(2,3)$  is second row and third column? If yes , then there are 3 - "+1" and 2 "-1", so the element will be "+1"

Comment: @openspace:  Yes, $(2,3)$ is second row, third column.  You set the rules, but I read closest to just mean the four nearest neighbors for a cell in the center and for this cell I would just see three:  the one above, to the left, and below.  Two of them are $-1$.  It sounds like you mean the eight cell neighborhood for the center cells, including the diagonals.  Please clarify.

Comment: @RossMillikan my bad. Thanks for note!

Comment: This would usually be stated in the language of cellular automata.  Your $+1$s are filled squares and $-1$s are empty.  Each operation is a generation.  There is a large literature.

Answer (score 1):

With the clarified neighborhood definition:

Here is a probabilistic approach.  Assume we start with a matrix that has each entry $1$ with probability $p$ and $-1$ with probability $1-p$.  We assume the matrix is large so we don't care about the boundary.  After one operation a cell becomes $1$ with probability $p^8+8p^7(1-p)+28p^6(1-p)^2+56p^5(1-p)^3$.  If we want to go towards a **$1$** matrix we need this to be greater than $p$.  According to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%5E8%2B8p%5E7(1-p)%2B28p%5E6(1-p)%5E2%2B56p%5E5(1-p)%5E3%3Dp), this is true when $p \gt 0.604487$ so we need a bit more than $\frac 35$ of the cells to start out as $1$.

On the other hand, a matrix that has two neighboring rows and two neighboring columns filled with $-1$s at the start will go to $-1$, so you can have as many as $(n-2)^2\ 1$'s and still go to $-1$.  I think a checkerboard matrix with a $3 \times 3$ block set to $1$ will eventually go to $1$, so you can have only half $1$s and get to a $1$ matrix.

Comment: Why probability should be so ?

Comment: I was assuming each cell in the middle had four neighbors.  The chance they are all $1$ is $p^4$ and the chance three of them are $1$ is $4p^3(1-p)$

Comment: I guess the idea about $(n-2)^2 matrix is false

Comment: It is correct.  Each cell that starts -1 has enough neighbors that it will never switch.  The $(3,3)$ cell starts $1$ but has five $-1$ neighbors so it will switch.  The $-1$s will propagate through the whole matrix

Comment: May I ask you : we compare probability with some value $p$ it's looks like true , but how can we explain it

Comment: I mean : why it should be more than $p$

Comment: For the random matrix, we want the number of $1$s to increase.  The chance at the first generation is $p$, while the chance at the second is the eighth degree polynomial I gave.  This assumes the $1$s are distributed randomly.  At the first generation we may be given this is true, but it is not really fair to assume the second generation is random as well.  There will be correlations in the locations of the $1$s.  I suspect there will be more clumping in the second generation, which is probably good for the $1$s, but a random second generation is the easy thing to check.

Comment: What will be if we consider $P(P \dots P(p)))$ , where $P(x)$ is given polynomial , maybe it will give the better approximation?

Comment: The root I cite is an unstable equilibrium.  If you start above it, iterating will converge to $1$ and if you start below it will converge to $0$.  The problem is that you can't say that $P(P(p))$ is the expected fraction of $1$s in the second generation because of the correlations of the $1$s in the first generation.